# Android keyboard enter button to keep keyboard visible

Tags: android

I'd like for my enter key to complete an action *without* hiding the keyboard afterwards. Currently every time I enter something and press the enter button the EditText input is cleared to accept the next input, but as the keyboard disappears I have to click the EditText again so that the keyboard would appear again...

Right now this is on my layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etCommand"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/commandHint"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend" >
</EditText>
```

And the code:

```
etCommand = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommand);
etCommand.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
            sendCommand();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

## EDIT

As swayam suggested I had to return `true` inside `onEditorAction` so that the OS would think the action was handled and leave it alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go at this code snippet :

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

Comment: Where did you add this code ? try putting it inside the onClick of the editText

Comment: Or maybe catch the EVENT_KEYCODE_ENTER ? That way the edit text would never register a carriage return and your keypad would not be hidden

Comment: So I have to force it to re-open every time? This seems like a lot of work for a functionality I don't want... oh well.

Comment: You can define a keyListener and catch the event every time ENTER is pressed. That should be a work around.

Comment: But in the current case I'm catching the `onEditorAction` and returning false, doesn't that count for something? The action should be overridden and the keyboard shouldn't disappear...

Comment: Forgive me if I am mistaken but doesn't returning false mean that the event has not been handled and the OS should handle the event ? Shouldn't it be true to let the OS know that you have handled the event ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16050/discussion-between-solenoid-and-swayam)

Answer (score 0):

Add the KeyListener for EditText for Enter key press and after the task completed requestfocus on edittext again would be solution